# require() doesn't consistently return methods appended to the exports object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I've been using require() to break my code up into modules, but the results of doing this seem to be sporadic and inconsistent.

For example, in main.js, I have two requires()s:

```
var moduleOne = require('cloud/moduleOne.js');
var moduleTwo = require('cloud/moduleTwo.js');
```

Calling methods which are appended to moduleOne via exports produces the correct result:

```
moduleOne.methodOne(argumentOne); // is defined
```

Where as doing the same thing to the second module doesn't. It tells me the method is undefined.

```
moduleTwo.methodTwo(argumentTwo); // is undefined
```

I'm really confused why this is so inconsistent. In each source file, I'm declaring the functions like so (There's no function wrapper to create a local namespace):

```
// moduleOne.js
exports.methodOne = function(argumentOne) {
    // Code
}

// moduleTwo.js
exports.methodTwo = function(argumentTwo) {
    // Code
}
```

My linter tells me all the code is valid, and code in moduleOne executes as expected and passes the tests I have for it. Has anyone else experienced this, and if so, what was the solution? Both files are indeed in the `cloud` directory and both of them are on Parse.

Comment: try exports.module.methodOne...

Comment: Try inverting the require() calls. What happens ? Do you only have moduleTwo defined ?

Comment: When I invert the require() calls, I still get the same results.


@Louis, I'm using the Parse API, which doesn't explicitly say that I need to configure RequireJS, so I haven't been. I already have a lot of code that's running using modules, but a few modules aren't getting properly loaded. Is this a common symptom of an improperly configured RequireJS instance? The Parse docs don't mention having to configure the RequireJS instance anywhere on their site, and state that it should work they way I'm using it.

Comment: @Louis I realized that Parse uses the Node require() and not the RequireJS require(). Sorry for the confusion - I'm a bit new to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If both the files implement methods similarly, then it might be a caching issue.
Try adding a cache buster to your require config:

```
urlArgs: "bust=" +  (new Date()).getTime()
```

See [the docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-urlArgs) for a reference.